# Find traceback of print caller

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a python program which interacts with many external libraries and has some fairly complex logic. In this program I've found that it'll sometimes print `NoneType: None` to the console (with no context) whatsoever. I have no idea where this is being printed or why and this is causing errors in other places of the program.

So is it possible to find the source of a print/warn call?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742501/is-there-a-trick-to-break-on-the-print-builtin-with-pdb

Comment: That worked great, thanks! Sorry for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the built-in `print()` function and then observe what's going on, for example:

```
import builtins
import inspect

builtin_print = builtins.print  # store a reference to the built-in print() function
def tracing_print(*args, **kwargs):
    c = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1]  # get the calling frame
    # print the caller info (you can add a condition like `if args and args[0] is None`):
    builtin_print("{}, line {}, caller `{}`, source: {}".format(c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]))
    builtin_print(*args, **kwargs)  # call the built-in method and forward the params
builtins.print = tracing_print  # override the built-in print
```

That will give you a ton of info preceding every call to `print()`. For example:

```
def foo():
    print("Bar!")
foo()
```

Will yield something like:

```
/tmp/playground/test.py, line 13, caller `foo`, source: ['    print("Bar!")\n']
Bar!
```

Needless to say, do not use this in production code, it's meant for forensics.